# How to add host redirect from secondary to primary domain using terraform and google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

For example, I have two domains: example.com and example.org.
I want to make primary domain example.com and setup host redirect (in google cloud terms) from example.org and www.* to example.com.
Intuitively it looks like I have to create two "path matchers", one of them will serve backend and another one do host redirect.

```
variable "primary_domain" {
  type    = string
  default = "example.com"
}

variable "secondary_domains" {
  type    = set(string)
  default = ["example.org", "www.example.com", "www.example.org"]
}

resource "google_compute_url_map" "landing_url_map" {
  name            = "landing-url-map"
  default_service = google_compute_backend_bucket.landing_backend_bucket.self_link

  host_rule {
    path_matcher = "primary"
    hosts        = [var.primary_domain]
  }

  path_matcher {
    name            = "primary"
    default_service = google_compute_backend_bucket.landing_backend_bucket.self_link
  }

  host_rule {
    path_matcher = "secondary"
    hosts        = var.secondary_domains
  }

  path_matcher {
    name = "secondary"
    default_url_redirect {
      host_redirect = var.primary_domain
    }
  }
}
```

But it fails:

```
Error: "path_matcher.1.default_url_redirect": conflicts with default_service

  on landing.tf line 47, in resource "google_compute_url_map" "landing_url_map":
  47: resource "google_compute_url_map" "landing_url_map" {
```

I've tried multiple other ways to make it work but none of them doesn't work. I make sure it works in the web console but can't find any way how to implement this using terraform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rollback to 3.25.0 helped

The issue has been reported on GitHub

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/6695

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you cannot have **default_service** at the top level of the URL map and have **default_url_redirect** in a path_matcher. Try removing `default_service = google_compute_backend_bucket.landing_backend_bucket.self_link` from the top-level as follows:

```
resource "google_compute_url_map" "landing_url_map" {
  name            = "landing-url-map"

  host_rule {
    path_matcher = "primary"
    hosts        = [var.primary_domain]
  }

  path_matcher {
    name            = "primary"
    default_service = google_compute_backend_bucket.landing_backend_bucket.self_link
  }

  host_rule {
    path_matcher = "secondary"
    hosts        = var.secondary_domains
  }

  path_matcher {
    name = "secondary"
    default_url_redirect {
      host_redirect = var.primary_domain
    }
  }
}
```

> When none of the specified hostRules match, the request is redirected to a URL specified by defaultUrlRedirect. If defaultUrlRedirect is specified, defaultService or defaultRouteAction must not be set. Structure is documented below.

From the [default_url_redirect argument docs for the google_compute_url_map](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_url_map.html#default_url_redirect).

Comment: I've tried to do this, but it seems to one of default_service or default_url_redirect is required to be on the top level of google_compute_url_map resource.

Comment: Diabolical. That means you'll need to use url_redirect instead of default_url_redirect. I couldn't find a simple example of url_redirect, but that may just be the documentation being overcomplicated.

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried to change to url_redirect but it says:

Error: Unsupported block type
Blocks of type "url_redirect" are not expected here.

I think this used to work. Might it be a regression or change in the google provider, perhaps from this fix? https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/pull/6547

Comment: Downgrading the Google provider from 3.27.0 to 3.25.0 seems to help. Probably confirms the theory that this fix introduced an incompatibility.

Comment: I reported a bug: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/6695